# Explode Joomla Content?

Tags: joomla, explode

I am creating a joomla template. In order to get the contents of a page I have this: `<jdoc:include type="component" />`

How can I explode this or add the contents of the component to a variable?

Comment: What happens when the page renders is that the component is included. Depending on what it is you actually want to do you would usually use plugins at some point in the process to access the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you shouldn't. The **right** way to modify the content before rendering it (assuming that's what you want to do) is to use [content plugins](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content) or [system plugins](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System).

Especially the "onAfterRender" plugin allows you to pick the current body, edit as you wish, and then push it back, e.g.

```
$body = JResponse::getBody();
$modifiedBody = doSomethingWith($body);
JResponse::setBody($modifiedBody);
```

Instead, if you just want to change the default layout of any component, you should look at [template override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)